# How do I create a private Maven repository on S3 from jar not .java file?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, amazon-s3, jar

I want to create a private Maven repository using AWS S3 from jar, because I must control a jar which is not registered Maven Central.

I searched the way to do that by google, but I could only search the way to create from a .java file by using Maven or Gradle like this(https://medium.com/@JacobASeverson/s3-maven-repositories-and-gradle-911c25cebeeb).

How do I create a private Maven repository on S3 from jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an artifactory with a private repository, the quickest way to do this is with [jfrog-artifactory-amazon-ec2](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/jfrog-artifactory-amazon-ec2/)

You can then add your private artifacts in a private repository (see [creating a repository](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/creating-new-repositories-in-version-4-x/))

Then you can create a [virtual repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) which will combine maven from the internet and your private repository.

Use this virtual repository in you settings.xml, it will see both private and public artifacts.